# Working of an electric motor

Tags: motor, dc-motor, motor-controller, ac-motor

Do motors run on an Ac source? If it does then do we need to convert ac into dc before supplying it to the motor?

Comment: There are different kinds of motors, which one is yours?

Comment: If we talk about ac motors then can we feed ac directly to the motor or is there a mechanism to first convert it into dc?

Comment: If it's the "correct" ac, you can directly feed it to the motor. If it is not, you have to convert it accordingly. You should provide more info about what you want to do.

Comment: @IshaRoy , you should also look up ***shaded pole*** motors when considering single phase AC motors which need to consistently turn in a particular direction. Other methods include a start and run capacitor. It is worth learning about these methods.

Comment: To answer this question we need to know what your motor is. Give us more details and we'll try and help, without more information it is all just guess work.

Answer (score 3):

There are both AC & DC motors available in the market. Ac motors run directly on the AC supply. The most commonly used ac motors are Single phase/3 Phase induction motors. If we have to use DC motor depending on the application and we have only Ac power supply we are required to convert ac voltage into appropriate Dc voltage required by the motor by means of rectifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Motors come in both AC and DC varieties. They use different physical arrangements (e.g. DC commutator) and have different characteristics. There are plenty of references on the net e.g. [http://www.ohioelectricmotors.com/2015/07/what-is-the-difference-between-an-ac-motor-and-a-dc-motor/#:~:text=A.C.%20motors%20are%20powered%20from,%2Dto%2DDC%20power%20converter.&text=A.C.%20induction%20motors%20do%20not,and%20have%20long%20life%20expectancies](http://www.ohioelectricmotors.com/2015/07/what-is-the-difference-between-an-ac-motor-and-a-dc-motor/#:%7E:text=A.C.%20motors%20are%20powered%20from,%2Dto%2DDC%20power%20converter.&text=A.C.%20induction%20motors%20do%20not,and%20have%20long%20life%20expectancies).

It is not necessary to convert AC to DC to drive an AC motor.

Answer (score 2):

Most AC motors run on an AC source with no need to convert AC to DC. For control purposes, AC is sometimes converted from AC to DC then back to AC. There are also DC motors that use DC directly, but perform switching inside the machine that is something like converting DC to AC.

Answer (score 2):

All electric motors run on AC; you need AC to create a rotating magnetic field.

Some run directly off an AC supply, while others create their own AC from a DC supply, either using brushes and a commutator, or electronic switching in brushless motors.

Answer (score 1):

There are AC, DC and Universal (AC & DC) motors. AC motors are run on an AC supply, DC on a DC supply and Universal on AC or DC as required.

Here's the case of a universal series motor, run on AC for uni-directional operation and on AC converted to DC for bi-directional operation.

[image]